# Heads or Tails with 3 coins until all 3 coins land on head

Tags: java

I can't seem to get this to work, as I am very stuck.
I don't know what to do in the if statement.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    Random coin1 = new Random();
    Random coin2 = new Random();
    Random coin3 = new Random();

    int count = 0;
    int heads = 0;

    System.out.println("Toss\tCoin1\tCoin2\tCoin3");

    while (heads < 3) {
        int c1 = coin1.nextInt(2);
        int c2 = coin2.nextInt(2);
        int c3 = coin3.nextInt(2);
        count++;
        if()

        System.out.println(count + "\t" +coin1 +"\t" + coin2 + "\t" +coin3);
```

Comment: Actually you don't really need an `if` statement. You just need to modify `heads` accordingly to represent how many heads you've got in the toss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assume that the `nextInt()` returns `1` if *heads* was tossed, then assign the sum of these values to `heads`.

```
heads = c1 + c2 + c3;
```

There is also an option to use the `if` if you used `nextBoolean()` instead of `nextInt(2)` which would return `true` if *heads* was tossed. Also modifying the variables to be `boolean` instead of `int` the code could look like

```
while (heads < 3) {
     boolean c1 = coin1.nextBoolean();
     boolean c2 = coin2.nextBoolean();
     boolean c3 = coin3.nextBoolean();
     count++;
     heads = 0;
     heads += c1 ? 1 : 0; //incrementing heads if c1 is true
     heads += c2 ? 1 : 0;
     heads += c3 ? 1 : 0;
     if(c1 && c2 && c3){ }
     System.out.println(count + "\t" + c1 +"\t" + c2 + "\t" +c3);
}
```

Also in `System.out.println(count + "\t" +coin1 +"\t" + coin2 + "\t" +coin3);` `coin1`  is a reference to a `Random` object, meaning this will print out something like `java.util.Random@74a14482` not the value of the coin toss. If you want to print `0` or `1` you need to print `c1` instead. (same with 2 and 3)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an `if`. Your random values are either `0` or `1`. Assuming a value of `1` stands for Head, you can count the number of heads using

```
heads = c1+c2+c3;
```

instead of that `if`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one instance of `Random`

```
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int count = 0,heads = 0;

    while (heads < 3) {
        int c1 = rnd.nextInt(2);
        int c2 = rnd.nextInt(2);
        int c3 = rnd.nextInt(2);
        count++;
        heads = c1+c2+c3;
        System.out.println(count + "\t" +c1 +"\t" + c2 + "\t" +c3);
    }
```

In case you want to print only the final result:

```
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int count = 0,heads = 0;
    int c1 = 0, c2 = 0, c3 = 0;

    while (heads < 3) {
        c1 = rnd.nextInt(2);
        c2 = rnd.nextInt(2);
        c3 = rnd.nextInt(2);
        count++;
        heads = c1+c2+c3;
    }
    System.out.println(count + "\t" +c1 +"\t" + c2 + "\t" +c3);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    //you can use only one rand obj to use Random()
    Random rand = new Random();

    //Initializing coins as 0
    //Values of coins will change once we get random 
    int coin1 = 0;
    int coin2 = 0;
    int coin3 = 0;

    //initializing heads and count as 0
    int heads = 0;
    int count = 0;

    while(heads < 3){
        //Assume '1' comes out for head and '0' for tail
         coin1 = rand.nextInt(2);
         coin2 = rand.nextInt(2);
         coin3 =  rand.nextInt(2);

         //if all three coins are '1' which is head; 
         //sum should be 1+1+1 = 3
         //while loop terminates because 3<3 is false
        heads = coin1+coin2+coin3;
        count++; //count = count +1;
    }
    //printing the value of count and coins
    System.out.println(count + "\t" +coin1 + "\t" + coin2 + "\t" +coin3);
```